# Tag suggestions

Tags: feature-request, tags

I respect that this is a new site and not all tags will be available. Who could possibly think of all of the tags that would be needed? No one.

In writing a question, I could only find one useful tag, medical.

I am suggesting a few more.

Elder Law
Medicare
Medicaid

I am sure we can think of more, however, this is a good start.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tags can be created by users with sufficient reputation - if they aren't attached to questions (or are attached to too few questions) they get deleted.

In fact, the only way tags get created is for users to add them to questions! We can't create orphan tags.

Comment: Okay. Thanks! I will look into this.